# NodeJS Websockets - terminate socket after sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, terminate

I'm using the ws package to create websockets in nodeJS.

However, what i'm trying to do is once data is sent to the server, the socket must terminate. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

My code now looks like this, but the problem here is terminate could before any data is sent.

```
        ws.on('open', function open() {
        console.log('subscribing');
        ws.send(creds);
        ws.terminate();
        resolve(1);
    });
```

What is the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you terminate it gracefully:

```
ws.close()
```

But be ware that you cannot know from server when the data has arrived to the client unless the client answers you back. So what you should do is to make another event, make sure the client has received the data and answers you back, then terminate his connection on that event.

```
    ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('subscribing');
    ws.send(creds);
});

    ws.on('credsanswer', function incoming(message) {
    //user has received creds ands calls us back
    ws.close()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** I may have switched client-side with server-side, but the concept still remains the same. You need an acknowledge signal to be sent back.

This is not a websocket problem. It is rather a TCP/IP problem. When you send data, you may know when it is flushed out of the network adapter's buffer, but you won't be able to tell when (or if) the last packet arrives on the other endpoint.

This is a common problem to all TCP/IP connections and the only absolutely secure solution I've found in several use cases is to send an ACK (acknowledge) back to the client like this.

On the server, once the message is received:

```
ws.send(""); // acknowledge the server received the message
// don't close the connection, linger instead
// process the message...
```

On the client:

```
// create ws and immediately set a flag
ws.lingering = false;

// attach receive event before you open the socket
ws.on("data", function () {
  if (ws.lingering)
  {
    // now you can terminate the connection
    ws.terminate();
    resolve(1);
  }
});

// now open the socket and send message without terminating, yet
ws.on("open", function () {
    console.log("subscribing...");
    ws.send(creds);
    ws.lingering = true;
});
```

As you may notice, the message sent by the server isn't checked on the client, it is just a signal to wait for.